# Missing Wiki_id to Collaborator model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partial

Im trying to add collaborators to wikis but i cant seem to be able to add the wiki_id to the collaborator model . Am i missing something, Im rendering the _form partial into the wiki show view.

i keep getting

```
<Collaborator id: 20, user_id: 9, wiki_id: nil,  >
```

## collaborator _controller

```
def create
  @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:wiki_id])
  @collaborator = @wiki.collaborators.build(collaborator_params)    
  if @collaborator.save
    flash[:notice] = "You Added a collaborator"
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Was not about to add collaborator. Please try again"
  end
  redirect_to wiki_path(@wiki)
end

def collaborator_params
  params.require(:collaborator).permit(:user_id, :wiki_id)
end
```

**_form partial**

```
<%= form_for [wiki, collaborator] do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :Premium %>
  <%= f.select :user_id, options_from_collection_for_select(User.premium, "id", "username") %>
  <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-default' %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: can you provide `collaborator_params` method?

Comment: `params.require(:collaborator).permit(:user_id, :wiki_id)`

Comment: remove `wiki_id` from arguments of `permit`

Comment: ok i have removed it

Comment: no same ` First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` for `<%= form_for [wiki, collaborator] do |f| %>` error is happening still.

Comment: can you show `new` action and piece of  view, where you render form ?

Comment: this is in the wiki#show view `  <%= render partial: 'collaborators/form',locals: {wiki: @wiki, collaborator: @collaborator}%>`  
and this is the new action in the collaborators_controller   `def new
    @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:wiki_id])
    @collaborator = Collaborator.new
  end`

Answer (score 1):

The code for building `@collaborator` should be:

**If the relation is `wiki has_one collaborator`**:

```
@collaborator = @wiki.build_collaborator(collaborator_params)
```

**If the relation is `wiki has_many collaborators`**:

```
@collaborator = @wiki.collaborators.build(collaborator_params)
```

Since I think the `collaborator_params` in your code is missing `wiki_id` param, that is why your new collaborator is missing `wiki_id`. Make it easy, use `build_collaborator` to build new collaborator, the `wiki_id` will be assigned automatically!

Comment: its a `has_many` model . and updated @wiki.collaborators.build(collaborator_params)  now im getting `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`  for `<%= form_for [wiki, collaborator] do |f| %>`

Comment: This is another problem in your code, please update your controller & view in detail, the last line of your controller code `<%= render partial: 'collaborators/form',locals: {wiki: @wiki, collaborator: @collaborator}%>
` is not relevant to controller anyway!

Comment: Sorry im not every good at asking questions on here but i have updated the controller and removed the render partial line

Comment: @MiguelAngelQuintana: I meant where is the place to render partial `_form`?, I think there is another view render that partial!, you didn't mention here, so could you update?

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned by **@Hieu pham** wiki_id missing in params, but you can add wiki_id like

```
@wiki = Wiki.find(params[:wiki_id])
@collaborator = Collaborator.new(collaborator_params)
@collaborator.wiki_id = @wiki.id
@collaborator.save
.....

...
```

Comment: I updated it to @collaborator = @wiki.collaborators.build(collaborator_params) but now im getting `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` for _form

Comment: @MiguelAngelQuintana Try my solution with code you added with this question, that will work for you